# Can I give admin role to Terraform for GCP? (example on Cloud Run domain mapping)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm having issues giving necessary GCP roles for Terraform, with many `Error 403: The caller does not have permission`.

The way I'm doing it is by adding gradually permissions, but it's more a trial and error approach, and I end up over adding authorizations.

Is there a way to give a full admin role to Terraform on GCP, as we can do on AWS? Or maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find docs on that topic online.

Thanks.

--

**Update:**

The resource I want to create is a domain mapping for Cloud Run. This is done with:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "default" {
  location = "europe-west1"
  name     = "mydomain.com"

  metadata {
    namespace = "default"
  }

  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  }
}
```

*P.S.: The domain was varified with Google Webmaster page.*

But the returned issue on `terraform apply` is:

`Error creating DomainMapping: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission`

To solve this particular issue, I need to find which authorization I need to add to my Terraform role, but it's just a matter of time before getting into the same issue again when requiring a new GCP service.

Also, I'm perfectly able to add mapping using the GCP console, which shows I was able to pass all the required verification steps.

Isn't it better to make Terraform admin on all GCP resources and let it create all necessary resources?

Comment: What do you want to do with terraform?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, I added an update on the question with more details

Comment: I think it's better if you limit api access until you're absolutely sure you'll need it. Obviously the other alternative is give Terraform GodMode permission to create everything

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 I agree, we should always restrict authorizations to what is necessary. Unfortunately, it's hard to find documentation on what authorizations to add when using a new Terraform resource. The doc of Terraform is fantastic when it comes to using the resource, but there is a missing part on the required authorizations. How can you find out which ones to add? For example, on `google_cloud_run_domain_mapping` I go with trial and errors picking random authorizations! This is not smart :(

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the fine grain details of GCP resources, but I'd imagine Cloud Run has its own subset of items... A domain mapping sounds like a VPC config

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using pre-defined over-privileged roles see the [understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-run-roles) document.

In the [link within Daniel's answer](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains), the document suggests that you can [Add verified domain owners to other users or service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#add-verified).

Once the service account is trusted for domain mapping provide `roles/run.admin` role to verify it solves the issue and then restrict it by [switching to a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) to adhere to least-privilege.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of adding a custom domain you'll need to refer to the following section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#adding_verified_domain_owners_to_other_users_or_service_accounts).

Notice that you'll need to add the service account as a verified owner in order to get the correct permissions.